# Aligning columns in DIV table

Tags: html, css-tables

CSS:

```
div {
    border:1px solid;
}
.divtable {
    display:table;
}
.divrow {
    display:table-row;
}
.divcol {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
}
.headrow {
    display:table-caption;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
}
```

Html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="divtable">
    <div class="headrow">
        <div class="divcol" style="background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='green'">Hostname</div>
        <div class="divcol" style="background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='green'">IP Address</div>
        <div class="divcol" style="background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='green'">Acknowledged</div>
        <div class="divcol" style="background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='green'">Date Discovered</div>
        <div class="divcol" style="background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='green'">Select</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divrow">
        <div class="content">johndoelaptop1.corp.testcompany.com</div>
        <div class="content">10.1.1.10</div>
        <div class="content">Y</div>
        <div class="content">2013-10-21</div>
        <div class="content"><input type='checkbox' name ='chk1' /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divrow">
        <div class="content">alicelaptop1.corp.testcompany.com</div>
        <div class="content">10.1.1.10</div>
        <div class="content">Y</div>
        <div class="content">2013-10-21</div>
        <div class="content"><input type='checkbox' name ='chk1' /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divrow">
        <div class="content">boblaptop1.corp.testcompany.com</div>
        <div class="content">10.1.1.10</div>
        <div class="content">Y</div>
        <div class="content">2013-10-21</div>
        <div class="content"><input type='checkbox' name ='chk1' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can some explain to me how I can get each column to line up correctly so that column 1 Row2 isn't spilling into column2 row 2.

For example:

> Hostname  IPAddress  Acknowledged  Date Discovered Select
>
> 1bclw050821.corp.wsfsbank.com   10.1.1.10 Y  2013-10-21

Comment: Do you have some CSS that you're not displaying here?

Comment: If it's a table why not use `<table>`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add CSS.....

Comment: I've read that you cannot set the limit on a div when using a table... so if my table is being populated dynamically the div will continue grow endlessly. That was my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `table-caption` for your header row.  It is a row, use `table-row`:

```
.headrow{
    display:table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLGyF/